# Hibernate, force get objects from Database

Tags: java, hibernate

If I add a new object and go .save() then run a select, the last object created, is retrieved from the classes, rather than the DB, which means a date property hasn't been converted into SQL format and its mucking up some frontend code of mine.

E.G

`Tue Feb 06, 2012` instead of `2012-02-06 00:00:00`

Is there a way to make sure all my objects get pulled from database?

Thanks

Comment: are you using any type of cache in between to fetch objects from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate has a few levels of cache. What you are experiencing is the session/first level cache. There is no way to disable that. But you can look into using a StatelessSession http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/batch.html Section 15.3 if you are insistent on doing something like this.

I advice you re-think your separation of User Interface, Business Logic and Persistence Layer if you are relying on the database to return correctly formatted date strings to your users. You shouldn't care how the Database or Hibernate formarts strings as long as you can understand the data you are storing/retrieving. Look into MVC, MVVM, or any other patterns of separation.

Comment: Ok I hear you, So I do have an MVC archtiecture, and the data displayed is on a completely separate page request after the insert has occurred which is why I wasn't expecting this to happen. I'm using an automated DTO class which sends back the object values in JSON format to my JS which then processes the date, it automatically calls the getDate accessor which I'm guessing invokes the Date.toString() method, thereby why I'm getting the standard format back. so I need to override the Date tostring waa

Answer (score 0):

by default your get() or load will read from Cache first and then go to database if not found in database. On which it also get added to cache. You will need session.get() with appropraite LockMode. Not the default LockMode.NONE.

Plus I believe it requires flush() also in between save() and get() to gaurantee that save operation has been synchronized to database.

Comment: Am I going about this the wrong way, I was thinking I'd leave the session open for the period of the website, I guess it never gets closed then. should I open and close it for each transaction?

Comment: Right O I've fixed this, everytime I commit an object I just close the sesion, then everytime I select the DB i get a fresh session I guess I will cahnge this so only close session when adding or updating.